# JavaFX Concurrency and Tasks (running threads in Task)

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, javafx, jssc

I am new to JavaFx/Concurrency so I read the tutorial over at [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) but I am still a little confused about the implementation of background threads in a JavaFX Gui.

I'm trying to write a small GUI that interfaces with some serial devices (using JSSC-2.8) and that updates the GUI based on the responses from those devices. But, there's a lag between when the message is written and when the device responds, and using Thread.sleep() for an arbitrary amount of time wasn't a reliable way for me program it. So instead I want to use wait() and notify() methods from the concurrency package (with all the appropriate synchronizations), but I am not sure how to implement it. What I initially did is create another Thread, inside the Task, that would write the messages and wait for the responses, and using some bindings, would update the GUI. I've included my code at the end. Here is a short form of the pseudocode I am trying to implement:

```
start Task:
  connect to serial devices
  synchronized loop: 
    send messages
    wait() for event to fire
      notify()
```

But what's been happening is, as soon as I call the wait(), the entire application idles and then when notify() is called (after the response fires and event), it doesn't continue where it left off in the recipe() loop, or the startTdk() loop for that matter, it's just idle. Have I implements the threads wrong? When I am calling the wait(), is it a possibility that I cause the EventDispatch or JavaFX Application Thread to pause?

I hope the question is clear, if there are any clarifications needed I can update the post.

```
public class OmicronRecipe extends Service<String> implements Runnable{

private final String SEPERATOR=";";
private final Tdk tdk;
private final Pvci pvci;
private final SimpleStringProperty data = new SimpleStringProperty(""); 
private final Float MAX_V = 26.0f,UHV=1e-8f;

private boolean isTdkOn=false, isPvciOn=false;
private String power;
private Float temp,press,maxT, setT;
private int diffMaxT,diffP,diffPow, diffT, index=0;

public OmicronRecipe(){
    tdk = new Tdk("COM4");
    pvci = new Pvci("COM5");
}

private synchronized void recipe(){
        while (true){
            try {
                sendMessages();
                data.set(power+SEPERATOR+temp+SEPERATOR+press);
                calcDiffs();
                if (diffPow < 0){
                    if(diffMaxT < 0){
                        if(diffT < 0){
                            if (diffP < 0){
                                if(!rampPow()){
                                    //Max Power reached
                                }
                            }else{
                                //Wait for pressure drop
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        //Wait until quit
                    }
                }else{
                    //Max power reached
                }
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(OmicronRecipe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
}

private synchronized boolean rampPow(){
    boolean isRamped=false;
    Float setPow = tdk.getSetPow(index), curPow;
    setT = tdk.getSetT(index);
    curPow = Float.parseFloat(power);
    if(curPow.compareTo(setPow) < 0){
        do{
            curPow += 0.1f;
            tdk.sendMessage("PV "+curPow+"\r");
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(OmicronRecipe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            curPow = Float.parseFloat(power);
        }while(curPow.compareTo(setPow) < 0);
        index++;
        isRamped=true;
    }
    return isRamped;
}

public synchronized boolean connect(){
    if(!isTdkOn && !isPvciOn){
        isTdkOn = tdk.connect();
        isPvciOn = pvci.connect();
    }
    return isTdkOn && isPvciOn;
}

public synchronized boolean disconnect(){
    if(tdk!=null && pvci !=null){
        isTdkOn = tdk.disconnect();
        isPvciOn = pvci.disconnect();
    }
    return !isTdkOn && !isPvciOn;
}

public synchronized StringProperty getData(){
    return data;
}

public void setMaxT(Float maxT){
    this.maxT = maxT;
}

private synchronized void calcDiffs(){
    Float pow = Float.parseFloat(power);
    diffPow = pow.compareTo(MAX_V);
    diffMaxT = temp.compareTo(maxT);
    diffT = temp.compareTo(100f);
    diffP = press.compareTo(UHV);
}

private synchronized void setListeners(){
    tdk.getLine().addListener((ov,t, t1)-> {
        synchronized (this){
            System.out.println("New Power: "+t1);
            power = t1;
            this.notify();
        }
    });
    pvci.getLine().addListener((ov,t,t1) ->{
        synchronized (this){
        String[] msg = t1.split(SEPERATOR);
        if(msg.length == 2){
            switch(msg[0]){
                case "temperature":
                    System.out.println("Temperaute");
                    temp = Float.parseFloat(msg[1]);
                    break;
                case "pressure":
                    System.out.println("Pressure");
                    press = Float.parseFloat(msg[1]);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Nothing; Something went wrong");
                    break;
            }
        }

            this.notify();
        }
    });
}

private synchronized void sendMessages(){
        try {
            tdk.sendMessage("PV?\r");
            this.wait();
            pvci.sendMessage("temperature");
            this.wait();
            pvci.sendMessage("pressure");
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OmicronRecipe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}

private synchronized boolean startTdk(){
    boolean isOut=false;
        if(isTdkOn){
            try {
                tdk.sendMessage("ADR 06\r");
                this.wait();
                System.out.println("Power: "+power);
                if(power.equals("OK")){
                    tdk.sendMessage("OUT?\r");
                    this.wait();
                    if(power.equals("OFF")){
                        tdk.sendMessage("OUT ON\r");
                        this.wait();
                        isOut = power.equals("ON");
                    }
                    else{
                        isOut = power.equals("ON");
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(OmicronRecipe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return isOut;
}

@Override
protected Task<String> createTask() {

    return new Task<String>() {
          @Override
          protected String call() throws IOException{
            new Thread(new OmicronRecipe()).start();
            return "";
          }
      };

}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (connect()){
        setListeners();
        if(startTdk()){
            recipe();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I won't include the Pvci class, because it just a copy of the Tdk class but with specific message sequences to talk with that machine.

```
public class Tdk {

private SerialPort tdkPort;
private final String portName;
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");;
private final StringProperty line = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private final HashMap<Float,Float> calibMap;
private ArrayList<Float> list ;
private boolean isEnd=false;

public Tdk(String portName){
    this.portName = portName;
    System.out.println("TDK at "+portName);
    calibMap = new HashMap();
    setMap();
}

public synchronized boolean connect(){
    tdkPort = new SerialPort(portName);
    try {
        System.out.println("Connecting");
        tdkPort.openPort();
        tdkPort.setParams(9600,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        tdkPort.setEventsMask(SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
        tdkPort.addEventListener(event -> {
            if(event.isRXCHAR()){
                if(event.getPortName().equals(portName)){
                    try {
                        if(!isEnd){
                            int[] str = tdkPort.readIntArray();
                            if(str!=null)
                                hexToString(str);    
                        }
                        if(isEnd){
                            System.out.println("Here: "+sb.toString());
                            isEnd=false;
                            String d = sb.toString();
                            sb = new StringBuilder("");
                            line.setValue(d);

                        }
                    } catch (SerialPortException e) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Tdk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tdk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    return tdkPort !=null && tdkPort.isOpened();
}

public synchronized boolean disconnect(){
    if(tdkPort!=null) {
        try {
            tdkPort.removeEventListener();
            if (tdkPort.isOpened())
                    tdkPort.closePort();
        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(Tdk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        System.out.println("Disconnecting");
    }
    return tdkPort.isOpened();
}

public synchronized void sendMessage(String message){
    try {
        tdkPort.writeBytes(message.getBytes());
    } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tdk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}

private void setMap(){
    calibMap.put(1.0f, 25.0f);
    calibMap.put(7.0f, 125.0f);
    calibMap.put(9.8f, 220.0f);
    list = new ArrayList(calibMap.keySet());
}

public Float getSetPow(int index){
    return list.get(index);
}

public Float getSetT(int index){
    return calibMap.get(list.get(index));
}

public synchronized StringProperty getLine(){
    return line;
}

private synchronized void hexToString(int[] hexVal){
    for(int i : hexVal){
        if(i != 13){
            sb.append((char)i);
        }else{
            isEnd=true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Turning: "+Arrays.toString(hexVal)+" to String: "+sb.toString()+" End: "+isEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Freeze**

Your UI freezes most probably because you are waiting on the FX Apllication Thread, to solve this there are different approaches:

---

**JavaFX Application Thread**

You can delegate some work to the FX Application Thread, therefore see [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)

Not everything can be run on this thread, but for example, in your DeviceController, you can wait until the message appears and then call Platform.runLater() and update the field (you should therefor oc hand the field over to the controller).

---

**DataBinding**
What you are describing can also be realised with [DataBinding](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm).
With this you could define a SimpleStringProperty, which is bound to your UI Label (.bind() Method). If the controller must fire its message you can set the StringProperty and the UI will update itself.
The scenario you described could be used like this:

```
start Task:
    connect to serial devices
    synchronized loop: 
        send messages
        wait() for event to fire
        **updateDate the DataBounded fields**
```

---

We are taught that, **Concurrency notify/wait**
Concurrency on level wait()/notify() is very low level. You should try to work with higher level synchronisation methods or helpers (where people have already solved your problems :))

Comment: I meant Idle's the application and not freezes it, my mistake. I updated my post. But I will look more into the DataBinding to see how I can implement it. Thank you

Comment: Binding probably won't work the way it's been described here.  Attempting to update an object observed by a GUI element in anything other than the FXAT will result in a runtime error.  So you'll still need to update the bound objects in a RunLater method.

Comment: I think you are partially right, I suggested handing the field reference over, this of course must runLater. But by DataBinding it should work independently, because you just change the property, the GUI thread is observing the property. Please correct me if im wrong (I also did not test is, just from what I remember how we did it).

Comment: About the wait and notify, what do you mean by higher synchronization? I solved by creating a service in the FXML controller and then that creates and runs a Thread to call OmiconRecipe.

Comment: The level of synchronisation reaches from very low (cue compareAndSwap) over lower (cue wait/notify) to higher (cue Locks,Semaphores etc.) to very high (ThreadPools, ExecutorServices, java.util.concurrent.* etc.).
This list is my own creation, there will be plenty more mechanism. What you basically have to know is: The wait / notify mechanism is something which has gone on peoples nerves, so someone developed a "tested, secure blabla* implementation, which you can use. Just check java.util.concurrent.* or 'AtomicInteger' or CountDownLatch etc :)